# how to low-level format a hard disk using AIX?

Tags: filesystems, aix, formatting

I have a server with AIX 6.1 , I formated some hdisks using diag tool, but in some way some of its VGDA survived.

how may I low-level format a hard disk using AIX?

or

how may I clear the VGDA of a specific hdisk?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

[Modern hard disks can't be low level formatted by the OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_formatting#Low-level_formatting_.28LLF.29_of_hard_disks), the factory does it once and it's permanent after that (except for damage).

If you're looking to zero out the drive, `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/[drive]` should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can completely erase a disk using `dd`, and then format it from there. Something like `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/<disk>`. Make sure it's the right disk before you do it though...

Answer (score 1):

To clear the VGDA run

chpv -C hdiskX

That should clear the owning volume group from a disk.